# Не могу получить данные из LiveData в UI

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, rxjava, livedata

я новичок в Андроид.
Во `ViewModel` использую `liveData(temperature)` в которую передаю данные из сервера при помощи **RxJava**.

```kotlin
class WeatherTodayViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    var temperature: MutableLiveData<WeatherResponse> = MutableLiveData()
    private val locationLifeDate = LocationLiveData(application)
    private val weatherRepository = WeatherRepository()
    private val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        compositeDisposable.dispose()
    }

    fun getLocationLifeData(): LocationLiveData = locationLifeDate

    fun fetchWeatherList(lat: Double, long: Double) {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            weatherRepository.getWeatherByLocationDetails(lat, long)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    temperature.postValue(it)
                }, {
                })
        )
    }
}
```

после этого во фрагменте в `OnViewCreated` вызываю два метода:

- Первый вызывает `fetchWeatherList` из `ViewModel` и данные, как я думаю, с сервера передаются в `LiveData temperature`.
- После этого вызывается второй метод который передает данные из `temperature` в `textView`. вот эти два метода

```kotlin
private fun requestLocationUpdates() {
    viewModel.getLocationLifeData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        viewModel.fetchWeatherList(it.lat.toDouble(), it.long.toDouble()).toString()
    })
}

private fun getTemperatureDetails() {
    viewModel.temperature.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        fragmentWeatherTodayBinding.tvTemperature.text = it.main.temp.toString()
    })
}
```

Но вся беда в том, что я не получаю данные в `textView`.
Возможно я неверно передаю данные в методе `fetchWeatherList`.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: А что у вас за `LocationLiveData`? Возможно там ничего не появляется и вся цепочка не срабатывает. Дебажить пробовали? Подписка приходит?

Comment: Eugene Krivenja. там я получаю GPS координаты для метода fetchWeatherList. Там все в порядке.

Answer (score 0):

Это рабочий код. Ошибка была в дата классе WeatherResponse